# Strange Normal Bake results

Tags: modeling, rendering, normals, baking, artifacts

I'm trying to bake a high poly rock onto a low poly one. I know my unwrap and low poly version aren't great but I am was just trying to make it quick for now.

I have tried baking out a simple cube with some detail on it and that worked fine but when I try my rock I can some strange results.

[image: Here is the Normal]
[image: Here you can see it gives the rock some pretty strange properties]
[image: Here is the detail I am trying to bake]

I've tried with and without a cage with no success.

Comment: can you add your blend file to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having weird issues with baking normal maps too. Including the one you're showing.

I think this particular problem is fixed by making sure the target low poly object has a unique Material. In my case it first shared the material with the high poly object.